# Louis Theroux, rhetorics and his documentaries

Tags: rhetoric, research

For my Audiovisual theory class I am required to do a research project. I have gotten 2 criteria that my research project should consist of. The first is about documentary film. The second is rhetorics. Now as a 'case' I have received the documentary film maker Louis Theroux. I am finding it  very hard to link rhetorics so his documentary's since I have no formal training in rhetorics.

I have researched the model about Ethos, pathos and logos for quite a bit. I have found that he acquires some pathos from his audience by being his naive self. And that he tries to blend in the extreme communities by being himself.

But really, I do not know  where to go from this point. I hope you can help me in any way.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something other than the English language

Comment: I am sorry, I was not sure where to ask my question. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: I'm not sure Theroux himself really goes in for "rhetoric". In his own words: [I'm not that comfortable doing polemic or being strident. It's not me. I think what I'm good at is getting to know people, and trying to build a relationship over a few weeks and trying to get to the truth.](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0857621/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bth_nm)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you study his interviews and try to identify when/how he starts to lead the interviewee towards his own opinions regarding something that is being discussed, perhaps a comment about a given location, rules or social group that implies (perhaps demands) a biased answer from the person that is being interviewed.

This might seem kind of vague so I can give you an example of rethoric through, let's say, the authority fallacy: If someone in the documentary states an opinion about *something* and reinforces the statement based on the fact that they are "experts", "founders" or "leaders" of a given group, that might not be a valid opinion but people tend to believe  that based on the idea of "authority" that is being shared.

e.g., a study says that women with blonde hair are smarter than brunettes -- That was published by Jane Doe, which is the Director of the center of Womens Research from Springfield.

Comment: This is a good kickstart, thank you! I will try to steer my research in this direction.